# sagemaker:CreateTrainingJob on resource: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1 training-job/object-detection-2019-12-10-07-43-06-930 with an explicit deny

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am using **amazon sagemake**r to perform object detection task and while running the exucution task i am facing this issue. Am i missing any policies in I am role?

the whole error is

SageMaker is not authorized to perform: sagemaker:CreateTrainingJob on resource: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:576481626755:training-job/object-detection-2019-12-10-07-43-06-930 with an explicit deny

Comment: do you have a customer managed policy for access to services? make sure sagemaker:* is added to the policy

Answer (score 0):

Do you have AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionPolicy-xxx and AmazonSageMakerFullAccess for your role? If not, try to add them. I am using these when deploying and using a model.

IN ADDITION: role = get_execution_role() was not working in some cases. In some cases, it only worked for me when I was explicitly used the name of the role:

```
model = SKLearnModel(
  model_data=artifact,
  role='AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-xxx',
  entry_point='script.py')
```

Comment: yes i have AmazonSageMakerFullAccess and mazonSageMaker-ExecutionPolicy-xxx .

Comment: are you using get_execution_role() ? See the additional information, I have added above.

Comment: I tried changing this too inside the code but its still showing the same error.